# Recover Post data from external form in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, ajaxform

My problem is the following : 
I have an external form in HTML and I have to send datas with AJAX to a Laravel application. 
So i created a simple form on the client side (http://localhost/myLaravelForm) :

```
<form action="http://localhost/laravelApp/public/task/addAjax" id="addNewTask" method="post">
    <label>Add task : </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name">
    <button type="submit" id="addTask">Send</button>
</form>
```

On the client side I created an AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function () {

       $('addNewTask').on('submit', function () {

            var taskName = $('#task-name').val();
            var csrf_token = '<%= token_value %>';

            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/monSuperProjet/public/task/addAjax",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    "name": taskName,
                    "token": CSRF_TOKEN
                },
                error: function (data) {
                   //something went wrong with the request
                    alert("Error");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log (data); 
                }
            });
           event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Now on the server side i created a Controller named Ajax :

```
class Ajax extends Controller
{
    public function receiveValues(Request $request) {
        var_dump (Task::find($request->input('name')))

    }
}
```

and created a route :

```
Route::post('/task/addAjax','Ajax@receiveValues');
```

Unfortunatelly I have awful errors.. 
I am a begginner in Laravel & Ajax and most generally in coding. We learn about our mistakes :))
I tried to find out some answers but unsuccessfully...
Thanks for your help

Comment: can you share with us those **awful errors**?

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246

Comment: Are you using api and the entire application is within the laravel.

Comment: Now i have this one because of a comma i forgot in the Controller
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

We can say so ...
The application is in Laravel (it's just the basic form presented in laravel website)... I created a second form "outside" and I will try to integrate it in Cordova ... so it requires only HTML, JavaScript & Jquery

Comment: You must provide an CSRF token for Laravel. Inside Laravel blade templates you can use `{{ csrf_token() }}`. If thats not possible you need to disable VerifyCsrfToken Middleware.

Comment: Should i insert an input hidden field which sends the token and Should i return a view containing the csrf_token in the Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

In the blade use this form:

```
 <form action="{{ url('/task/addAjax') }}" id="addNewTask" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <label>Add task : </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="task-name">
        <button type="submit" id="addTask">Send</button>
    </form>
```

If your using form submit then why do you want to do ajax. If you are interested in ajax then set the value of action in the form as `action=""` and then do your ajax. If you want to do it via ajax then try this(but set the action=""):

```
$.ajaxSetup(
        {
          headers:
          {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          "Your code comes here".
        });
```

Comment: In fact i'm not using the blade form .... i'm submitting a form outside from Laravel even from another host domain ... My outside form need to communicate with Laravel and Laravel need to send back a result .... Thanx for your answer

Comment: Then are you doing any api calls. Instead of doing var_dump() try doing return $request->all(); and see what you get in request. Then you can further simplify it.